# Terraform - Optional Nested Variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to create a module for Sagemaker endpoints. There's an optional object variable called `async_inference_config`. If you omit it, the endpoint being deployed is synchronous, but if you include it, the endpoint deployed is asynchronous. To satisfy both of these usecases, the `async_inference_config` needs to be an optional block.

I am unsure of how to make this block optional though.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. See example below of structure of the optional parameter.

**Example:**

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_endpoint_configuration" "sagemaker_endpoint_configuration" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0

  name = var.endpoint_configuration_name
  production_variants {
    instance_type          = var.instance_type
    initial_instance_count = var.instance_count
    model_name             = var.model_name
    variant_name           = var.variant_name
  }
  async_inference_config {
    output_config {
      s3_output_path = var.s3_output_path
    }
    client_config {
      max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance = var.max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance
    }
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    ignore_changes        = ["name"]
  }

  tags = var.tags

  depends_on = [aws_sagemaker_model.sagemaker_model]
}
```

**Update:** What I tried based on the below suggestion, which seemed to work

```
dynamic "async_inference_config" {
    for_each = var.async_inference_config == null ? [] : [true]
    content {
      output_config {
        s3_output_path = lookup(var.async_inference_config, "s3_output_path", null)
      }
      client_config {
        max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance = lookup(var.async_inference_config, "max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance", null)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `dynamic` block [1] in combination with `for_each` meta-argument [2]. It would look something like:

```
dynamic "async_inference_config" {
    for_each = var.s3_output_path != null && var.max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance != null ? [1] : []
    content {
    output_config {
      s3_output_path = var.s3_output_path
    }
    client_config {
      max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance = var.max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, you could come up with a different variable, say `enable_async_inference_config` (probalby of type `bool`) and base the `for_each` on that, e.g.:

```
dynamic "async_inference_config" {
    for_each = var.enable_async_inference_config ? [1] : []
    content {
    output_config {
      s3_output_path = var.s3_output_path
    }
    client_config {
      max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance = var.max_concurrent_invocations_per_instance
    }
  }
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Comment: I'm getting an error: │ The argument "async_inference_config.0.output_config.0.s3_output_path" is required, but no definition was found.

I set the s3_output_path as null in the variables.tf

Comment: Which method did you go for, the one with a new variable or the one with multiple variables in for_each?

Comment: I tried both. I adapted your suggestion and used lookups. Added an update in the original post. Not sure if that's best practice though. I'm a terraform novice.

Comment: If I were to choose, I would go with the second approach. Which combination of parameters caused the error?

Comment: Both approaches complained of the same error. Was saying I needed to make the s3_output_path non null and a string greater than length 1

Comment: And which value have you assigned in the second approach to the `enable_async_inference_config` variable?

Comment: default = false

Does it need to be null?

Comment: No, that's fine. Even with that it's complaining about the `s3_output_path`?

Comment: Yes that's right. Still complains about the nested variables even though enable_async_inference_config is set to false

Comment: Wait, is the code you are currently using the same one as in the question update? That's wrong.

Comment: Yes - that's one I'm using (in the update). It seemed to be working though.

Comment: Well, that's not the same as in the answer, so the one from the answer should be working.

Comment: Oh no, I think there's confusion. I tried the 2 proposed solutions that you suggested and they both didn't work (as discussed above, it returned that s3_output path error), so I adapted your solution a bit. The result of the adaptation is in the answer update, which seemed to work.